# Why are agents/browsers allowed to change URL without actually navigating to that path?

Tags: javascript, url, user-agent

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560617/how-to-change-url-in-browser-without-navigating-away-from-page) deals with changing the URL in browser without actually navigating to that URL. I have also stumbled across several Web sites where this is used and I find it confusing / misleading for the user and I am wondering why is this allowed in the first place.

**Question:** Why are agents/browsers allowed to change URL without actually navigating to that path? What is the gain in allowing this while the downside is confusing the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webapps have long been capable of changing the page's contents entirely using just JavaScript. For example, in Twitter you could navigate from main timeline to a profile to a specific tweet *entirely client-side,* without any page reloads – just JavaScript based updates.

The problem with that is that it becomes impossible to copy, bookmark, or share the URL you're seemingly on. If you start at `https://twitter.com` and open e.g. a tweet or a profile page, your address bar still thinks you're at `https://twitter.com`. You can't really click the "Back" button either – you'd leave the whole app.

Many websites tried to work around this by changing just the `#hash` part of the URL (that's used for internal page links), usually in a way that makes it look similar to a real path – e.g. clicking on @stackoverflow changes it to `https://twitter.com/#!/stackoverflow`.

Now the URL is copyable and bookmarkable, but still has problems – it's only understood by client-side JS, and not by search engines or browsers with JS disabled/blocked or even HTTP tools like wget/curl. To all these tools and programs, the part after # is meaningless (as it points to dynamically JS-generated data and not to a real name= or id=).

This is why the API has been added to generate "real" history events through JS – it allows each JS-based page to have an URL exactly corresponding to a real server-based page. When you click on a profile link, JS generates the same page that you'd have gotten without JS (only faster) and therefore it has the same URL as well.

If you use this API, you're of course supposed to only generate paths that actually exist on the server and correspond to real URLs – like in the above example, when JavaScript changes the URL to `https://twitter.com/stackoverflow`, that's fine because this is a real page that can be visited later, with the same contents and all. It just happens that the page was *loaded* via JS and not via navigation, but this difference is supposed to be practically invisible.

So "the downside is confusing the user" is only true when the API is *misused*, e.g. generating URLs which the server doesn't recognize later.